# Opening browser in client machine through ssh

Tags: ssh

Using linux, this link explains how to open a browser in the remote machine using ssh:

https://superuser.com/questions/583608/opening-browser-in-remote-machine-through-ssh-closed

How can I do to see the remote machines browser on the client computer?
Sort of as with xclock...